# Gulp forEach error

Tags: javascript, gulp

Using Gulp I need to search my files for a string and log to the console when this string is found.

The following works when I search for a string that is present in every file.

```
function logMatches(regex) {
  return map(function(file, done) {
    file.contents.toString().match(regex).forEach(function(match) {
      console.log(match);
    });
    done(null, file);
  });
}

var search = function() {
  return gulp.src(myfiles)
    .pipe(logMatches(/string to search for/g));
},
```

However if the string isnt in every file then I get errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
```

I know that there are results from the regex match as they are being logged to the console (before the error).

Comment: Is that `map` function from a well known library? Also, can you specify some inputs and expected outcomes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your inline function is called multiple times (I guess that's what `map` is supposed to do).

The first time, the regex matches, as you can see correctly in your console log.

But the second time, it doesn't match. So, `.match(regex)` returns null, and you are effectively calling `null.forEach(...)`, hence the error.

Try checking your regex result before calling `forEach` on it:

```
  return map(function(file, done) {
    var contents = file.contents.toString();
    var matches = contents.match(regex);
    console.log(contents, matches); // Here you can see what's going on
    if(matches) matches.forEach(function(match) {
      console.log(match);
    });
    done(null, file);
  });
```